# Is it possible for DNA from two male cousins to appear to have the same father in the sibling test?

Tags: dna

If a buccal swab is taken from a cousin of a man. (ie his uncle's son) and it was
 compared to that man's DNA in a sibling test, would it be possible for a false 
  positive test result showing that they were half siblings?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would.

The relationship estimator is based on the number of shared chromosomes. The normal range for a half-sibling is 1317cM to 2312cM. The normal range for a 1st cousin is from 553cM to 1225cM. It's very possible that a larger amount of DNA is shared between the two brothers (uncle and father), and that by chance a larger percentage is also shared between the cousins, bringing them to the half-sibling range.

It's possible, but not very likely though...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this would happen if the uncle and the father were identical twin brothers.

Otherwise, it's pretty rare -- not impossible, but rare -- for two "first cousins" to have so much DNA in common that they register as if they were half-siblings.